# exception on on listing files inside assets folder

Tags: android

i want to print,for testing the content of two folder inside assets folder.

the folder is composed:

assets

- foo.txt
- foo1.txt

but the program says to me that there aren't files.

```
AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
            String[] files = null;
            try {
                files = assetManager.list("");
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
                File file = new File(files[i]);
                try {
                    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);
                    while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
                        Log.e(" ", " " + scanner.next());
                    }
                    scanner.close();
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
```

logcat

```
10-06 19:38:16.328: W/System.err(12250): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /foo.txt: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
10-06 19:38:16.335: W/System.err(12250):    at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:416)
10-06 19:38:16.335: W/System.err(12250):    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:78)
10-06 19:38:16.343: W/System.err(12250): Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
10-06 19:38:16.351: W/System.err(12250):    at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
10-06 19:38:16.351: W/System.err(12250):    at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:110)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use the File class for a 'file' in assets folder. This is because File can only handle real files on the file system. Instead your only option is to call assets manager to open an inputstream fot the assets file and read from that stream. Examples have been posted many times on this forum.

Answer (score 1):

The [`AssetManager.list`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/AssetManager.html#list(java.lang.String)) gives a path that is relative within the assets. If you need to open a file, you need to provide an absolute path of the file. For assets files, you can use the [`AssetManager.open`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/AssetManager.html#open(java.lang.String,%20int)) method.

Comment: Of course there is no "absolute path" of the object in question, because by the time it gets to the device it is no longer actually a file.